# How do I know the scout data is acquired when tub is on the top or at the 90 degree from DICOM header?

Tags: dicom

When I receive scout images, where I can find the x-tube angle information from the DICOM header? Basically I need to know the scout was taken when x-tube is at the top or it is at the 90 degree or any other degree.

Comment: I do not think there is a specific tag for the angle; however, if what you need is to find out the localizer orientation with regards to the patient, you should use Image Orientation Patient (0020,0037).

Answer (score 2):

The precise answer to your question depends on the type (SOP Class UID) of DICOM object that your question refers to. AFAIK, the tube position is never encoded in DICOM headers, however, what you probably want to know is the orientation of the image plane in the patient coordinate system.

Most commonly (for CT/MR) this is encoded in the attribute (0020,0037) Image Orientation Patient which contains 6 floating point numbers describing the x,y,z components of the row and column vector of the image.

Please note that this orientation refers to the other slices of the same scan, there is no absolute reference coordinate system.

If this attribute is missing, (0020,0020) Patient Orientation may give you a hint, but not as precisely as the vectors.